# How is forecasting values for stationary time series even possible?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, stationarity

Forecasting future values for a time series using Holt-Winter's model makes a lot of sense: by identifying a trend and some seasonal patterns which are likely to repeat in the future one can make predictions for future values.

However, many models including the ARMA model expect the time series to be stationary meaning it has a constant mean (i.e. no trend), constant standard deviation and no seasonality. How is predicting future values of such a time series even possible?

The autoregressive model is a linear model which uses past values to predict future observations. I see it working with a time series with a linear trend (e.g. next value is 1.2 times the last value) or with changing standard deviation  (e.g. next value is -1.2 times the last value). But if both the mean and standard deviation must remain constant, how can a linear model work here?

The same question goes also for any other model operating on stationary series.

Comment: "Stationarity" is unfortunately not very well defined. Some authors define *strict stationarity* and *weak stationarity* and immediately say that by "stationarity" they will from now on mean weak stationarity. However, it often (and here) does not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

I very much recommend section 1.4 in [Shumway & Stoffer, *Time Series Analysis and Its Applications* (4th ed.)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-52452-8). They introduce *strict stationarity* and *weak stationarity*, and immediately say that by "stationarity" they will mean the weak kind.

Now, a weakly stationary time series has two properties:

1. The mean $\mu_t$ at time $t$ does not depend on $t$.
2. The autocovariance $\gamma(s,t)$ between times $s$ and $t$ only depends on the distance between them, i.e., on $|s-t|$.

Taken together, this means that a weakly stationary series has constant *marginal* means... however, the *conditional* means can definitely carry information we can use in forecasting. Essentially, if we can get a handle on the autocovariance function *and have observed realizations $x_t, \dots, x_T$, then we can combine the two pieces of information to improve our forecasts for times $T+1, \dots$, *conditional* on the tail of the observed values. And that is precisely what ARIMA does.